# Using dynamic variable names in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using `tkinter` and I have eight entry boxes named as:

```py
b1_entry
b2_entry
b3_entry
b4_entry 

c1_entry 
c2_entry 
c3_entry
c4_entry
```

I want to add them in groups and assign the answer to respective variables `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, so that I may display them in other entry widgets.

I want to use a `for` loop in python so that I can take the variable names in the form of `i`. It will be something like:

```py
for i in range (2, 5):
    f + str('i') = 'b' + str(i).get() + 'c' + str(i).get()
```

So in this way `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4` will be filled with relevant values.

Can you help me in getting the code right, please?

Comment: Don't make new variables. That's not maintainable if you want to change the number of variables. Just use lists.

Comment: don't dynamically create variables, use a *container*, like a `list` or a `dict`